# How to get sensor world pose from a SensorPlugin?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How can I get the world pose of a sensor from inside a SensorPlugin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6947/how-to-get-sensor-world-pose-from-a-sensorplugin?/) by [Bryan Newstrom](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/955/bryan-newstrom/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can use `Sensor::GetPose()` to get the pose offset of the sensor from its parent, but getting the world pose of the parent depends on the sensor type.

Most sensors are attached to links, though force torque sensors are attached to joints. For sensors with a link parent, you can do:

```
sensors::SensorPtr sensor;
physics::WorldPtr world;
std::string parentName = sensor->GetParentName();
physics::EntityPtr parent = world->GetEntity(parentName);
// The order here matters
math::Pose sensorPose = sensor->GetPose() + parent->GetWorldPose();
```

For force torque sensors,

```
sensors::ForceTorqueSensor sensor;
physics::JointPtr parent = sensor->GetJoint();
math::Pose sensorPose = sensor->GetPose() + parent->GetWorldPose();
```

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1